# Errors when trying to test app on iPhone

Tags: ios, linker-errors

When I try to test my app on the iPhone I get the following errors:

[image]

However I do not get these errors when running on the iOS Simulator.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Have you included the AVFoundation framework?

Comment: @Undo Hi, I just added it and it worked but why was I not getting the errors while using the simulator???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the AVFoundation framework for this to work, through the target page in Xcode. The Simulator, since it's running on OS X, handles things related to frameworks differently then the device does.